# Multiple purpose-specific setintervals or a single super interval

Tags: javascript, performance

For code practice and improvement purposes I am writing a simple game (currently writing it generic enough to be a game engine).

I currently have numerous `setInterval` calls running, namely each "entity" (prefab/player) looking at keys held down, checking for collisions, updating position references etc. I was just wondering what sort of performance issues (if any) could arise from a high number of separate setIntervals. Their timing in relation to each other isn't important, so I'm not worried about them falling out of sync (they have slightly different intervals anyway), but would a single `setInterval` that loops through all entities to run all the checks actually be more efficient? My only worry with that option, is that the function could take longer than the interval time. Does creating new intervals create enough stress to be worrying about, when each one does quite a small amount?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I wouldn't use `setInterval` since the callbacks could potentially stack up and occur one after the other if the code within the callback takes longer to execute than the interval.

As for having multiple timers, I do not think that it's a good idea, even if you do not care about synchronization. It makes the overall thing way too complex to maintain and would become a nightmare if you wanted to regulate your game speed. I would definitely go for a single timer.

Also, if you aren't aware aleady, there's the [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) function that's optimized for performing animations so you could use that instead of `setTimeout`. It will basically get called at 60fps if the browser can keep up.

You can use the `timestamp` passed as argument to the callback function passed to `requestAnimationFrame` to determinte how much time was elapsed since the last game loop iteration.

Comment: Right, yea I had looked briefly into the requestAnimationFrame method, but never made anything with it. I've started re-working the handling and added game "ticks" which are the frames. To keep the code logically separated however I'm adding to the game's "tick functions" from the respective other areas.. Will need to see how well this actually fares for what I'm trying to achieve, but will certainly +1 for now

Comment: @SmokeyPHP So what did you end-up doing? Have you considered accepting the answer as well?

Comment: Well I've not really done much since asking the question as it's just a little side project, but it looks like it's going to work out. I've set up a way to dynamically add/remove process to be run per tick/frame. Each one able to have a different delay specified. Looks ok so far, so will indeed accept and just create a new question if an issue crops up - thanks for your input